# Nautilus cannot handle "sftp" locations via x11

Tags: ubuntu, nautilus, x11-forwarding

I'm logging into my home computer (Ubuntu 10.04) via ssh, and now I want to open a remote connection (one that is stored in my bookmarks).

Nautilus tells me "Nautilus cannot handle "sftp" locations via x11".

Why might this be?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when I removed the package gvfs-backends and solved the problem by reinstalling that package.  Nautilus recommends, but is not dependent on gvfs-backends, which it appears to use for the virtual file system that is created to allow you to navigate an ftp server as a drive.